# How to create <img> element including a Django static src using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

I would like to create an img element using jQuery. Since I work with Django I will have to reference the imagefile by the static variable. I tried different solutions to come about this but the server can't load the image since the browser gets the wrong url.

I loaded static initially, all of the other static files load just fine.

This is my code which is located in the related .js file:

```
// foo.js included in foo.html which extends base.html

// Create Image element
 var arrowImage = $('<img />', {
   id: 'arrowImage',
   src: '{% static \"images/arrow.svg\" %}',
 });

// 
src: '{% static "images/arrow.svg" %}',

//
src: "{% static 'images/arrow.svg' %}",

//
src: "{% static \"'images/arrow.svg'\" %}",
```

***Error:***

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%%20static%20%22images/arrow.svg%22%20%%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

I have a base.html which is extended by foo.html where the element shall be created. The .js file that contains the code above is included as static in the foo.html file.

using this solution, I get the correct DOM created actually:

```
            // Create Image element
            var arrowImage = $('<img />', {
              id: 'arrowImage',
              src: "{% static \'images/arrow.svg\' %}",
            });
```

Which outputs:
[image]

Any solution for this?

Comment: Did you load static in your file before you call it?

Comment: Yes, I do have a bunch of other files that load just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you provide more information about where the code above is being run?

It might be that you are running this in a `js` file, itself being served as a static file. If that's the case, then Django isn't running the content of the file through the tempalte system, so the template tag isn't getting parsed.

Please tell us more about how you're serving the content to the browser, and it will be easier to help.

Your options here are:

1. Hard code the image paths. Less flexible, but you could reproduce Django's `STATIC_ROOT` as var in JS somewhere.
2. Serve the JS in a way that gets processes by the template system. This isn't so hard, but will mean running some python for every request to the file path
3. Condiser some way of adding the image paths to the HTML that can be read by the JS. Depending on what you're doing, this might help with using JS for progressive enhancement (unless the images are only needed by the JS elements)